# How to take this Grassmann integral?

Tags: integration, operator-theory, quantum-field-theory

I'm trying to reconstruct and understand what is explained in a paragraph of [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1307.7726). I am trying to check if the method they describe actually gives us the [Laughlin state](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laughlin_wavefunction). The integral I'm facing is:

$$ \small{|\psi\rangle \propto\int[d\xi d\chi]\prod_{\text{edges}\langle xy \rangle} e^{\xi_{x}^{t}.A.\xi_{y}+\chi_{x}^{t}.A.\chi_{y}}\prod_{\text{sites}\, z}e^{\xi_{z}^{t}.B.\xi_{z}+\chi_{z}^{t}.B.\chi_{z}}\left(1+\left(\xi_{z}^{t}.\kappa.c_{\xi,z}^{\dagger}\right)\left(\chi_{z}^{t}.\kappa.c_{\chi,z}^{\dagger}\right)\right)|0_{\xi},0_{\chi}\rangle} $$

where $\chi $ and $\xi$ are Grassmann variables each laying in a layer of a 2D plane on top of each other, and $\vec x, \vec y\ \text{ and } \vec z$ are 2D vectors addressing the sites on these layers ($N\times N$ integer square lattice with periodic boundary conditions). Also the $c^\dagger$s are fermionic creation operators. The Matrices $A,B$ and $\kappa$ are chosen such that:

$$\xi_{x+\text i}^t.A^h.\xi _x=\left( \begin{array}{cc} \xi_{x+\text i}^2 & \xi_{x+\text i}^4 \end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{cc}-i & \lambda \\ -\lambda & -i \end{array} \right)\left( \begin{array}{c}\xi_{x}^1 \\ \xi_{x}^3 \end{array}\right)$$

$$\xi_{x+\text j}^t.A^v.\xi _x=\left( \begin{array}{cc} \xi_{x+\text j}^2 & \xi_{x+\text j}^4 \end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{cc}1 & \lambda \\ -\lambda & -1 \end{array} \right)\left( \begin{array}{c}\xi_{x}^1 \\ \xi_{x}^3 \end{array}\right)$$

$$\xi_{x}^t.B.\xi _x=\left( \begin{array}{cc} \xi_{x}^2 & \xi_{x}^4 \end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{cc}0 & -2\lambda \\ 2\lambda & 0 \end{array} \right)\left( \begin{array}{c}\xi_{x}^1 \\ \xi_{x}^3 \end{array}\right)$$

$$\xi_x^t .\kappa .c_x ^\dagger = \kappa_1 \xi_x^1c_{x,1}^\dagger+\kappa_2 \xi_x^2 c_{x,2}^\dagger$$

The matrices work the same for $\chi$s.

---

### Some background about these integrals from the paper:

**Gaussian fermionic TNS$^1$:** the square lattice $\mathbb Z^2 \subset \mathbb R^2$ is generated by the two vectors $\text i = (1,0)$ and $\text j =(0,1)$. Our physical degrees of freedom are fermions, with 2 orbitals per site; the creation/annihilation modes obey the canonical anti-commutation relations $\{c_{x,\alpha}^\dagger , c_{x',\alpha '}\}=\delta_{\alpha,\alpha'} \delta_{x,x'}$. The fermion vacuum $|0\rangle $ is annihilated by all the $c_{x,\alpha}$. A class of translation-invariant Gaussian TNSs is constructed as follows: to every site $x$, we associate a set of **(real)** Grassmann variables $\xi_x^p,p\in \{1,2,3,4\}$. To every edge $\langle x' x \rangle (x'\in \{ x+\text i,x+ \text j \})$, we associate the expression $$e^{\sum_{p,q}\xi_{x+\text i}^p A_{pq}^h \xi_x^q} \text{   or   } e^{\sum_{p,q}\xi_{x+\text j}^p A_{pq}^v \xi_x^q}$$ with $A_{pq}^h,A_{pq}^v \in \mathbb C$. The superscripts $h,v$ stand for "horizontal" and "vertical". To every site $x$(on each layer), we associate a weight and a generating function of physical particles onsite: 
$$e^{\sum_{p,q}\xi_x^p B_{pq}\xi_x^q}\times e^{\sum_{p,\alpha}\xi_x^q \kappa_q^\alpha c_{x,\alpha}^\dagger}$$
with $B_{pq}=-B_{qp}\in \mathbb C$ and $\kappa_p^\alpha \in \mathbb C$. Grassmann variables anticommute with the physical creation/annihilation operators; thus the two exponentials in the above formulas all commute, both onsite and on different sites. Integrating out the grassmann variables will give us the translational invariant state.

**In my case** we have two copies of the above construction in two different layers(hence $\xi$ and $\chi$) with a constraint which translates into the integral I have written above. I would appreciate if anyone can help me take this integral; then we can move back to first quantization and see if we get the Laughlin state.

---

$\scriptsize{^1 \text{Tensor network state}}$